# Prevent notification drawer from collapsing after button click

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a media player application with a control notification, play, next, previous.

When I click on one of these buttons, the complete notification drawer collapses.

How do I prevent the collapsing?

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationPlayerControlReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(interpret);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_previous, "", pIntent);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_play, "", pIntent);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.av_next, "", pIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    return builder.build();
```

Comment: can u share your code?

Comment: sure, but there is nothing special about it

Comment: Im not sure but i think the problem will be with your intent or pendingintent

Comment: also  add builder.setContentIntent(pIntent);

Comment: Tried every PendingIntent Flag, also added setContentIntent, still no change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way things are supposed to work when the user clicks on a button that fires a PendingIntent created with PendingIntent.getActivity(); presumably if a button in a notification navigates to a new activity, you want the notification panel to get out of the way so you can see it.

If you want to implement transport controls in your notification, use [PendingIntent.getBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) or [.getService()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getService%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29).